# Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /directory/avatar.php on line 72

Tags: php

Wassup fellow coders, i stumbled upon a weird error regarding my Image Layering php script for an avatar on a project i'm working on. Does any of you perhaps know the reason why its giving me an error like that? Because its the first time im seeing this error lol.

Here is the code btw:

```
<?php include "MISC/trueconnect.php"; 
if($_GET['id']){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getUser = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id='$id'");
} $avatar = $getUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


$Body = $avatar->package;
if (empty($Body)) {
$Body = "Avatar";
}


$BottomID = $avatar->pants;
if (empty($BottomID)) {
$BottomID = "CharacterBG";
}

$ShirtID = $avatar->shirt;
if (empty($ShirtID)) {
$ShirtID = "CharacterBG";
}

$HatID = $avatar->hat;
if (empty($HatID)) {
$HatID = "CharacterBG";
}

$ToolID = $avatar->accessory;
if (empty($ToolID)) {
$ToolID = "CharacterBG";
}

$ScarfID = $avatar->mask;
if (empty($ScarfID)) {
$ScarfID = "CharacterBG";
}


$FaceID = $avatar->face;
if (empty($FaceID)) {
$ToolID = "CharacterBG";
}




class StackImage
{
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    
    public function __construct($Path)
    {
        if(!isset($Path) || !file_exists($Path))
            return;
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($Path);
        imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
        imagealphablending($this->image, true);
        $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
    }
    
    public function AddLayer($Path)
    {
        if(!isset($Path) || !file_exists($Path))
            return;
        $new = imagecreatefrompng($Path);
        imagesavealpha($new, true);
        imagealphablending($new, true);
        imagecopy($this->image, $new, 1, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($new), imagesy($new));
    }
    
    public function Output($type = "image/png")
    {
        header("Content-Type: {$type}");
        imagepng($this->image);
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
    
    public function GetWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }
    
    public function GetHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }
}
$Image = new StackImage($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/CharacterBG.png");
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$Body);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$FaceID);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$BottomID);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$ShirtID);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$ScarfID);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$ToolID);
$Image->AddLayer($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/CDN/ITEMS/".$HatID);
$Image->Output();

?>
```

Thanks!
~Grizler

Comment: It can only come from `imagecopy($this->image`, so that would mean `$this->image` is null then. But since `imagecreatefrompng` should return `false` and not `null` when it fails, it probably rather means it did not even get to that point of creating the image - but that your constructor function returned before it even initialized this property, in which case it should default to `null`. So presumably `file_exists($Path)` wasn't actually true then.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. Parameter 1 doesn't get the resource parameter but get's null. Do you also think about why it could be null? You can use `print_r($variable)` to see if parameter 1 is actually null.

Comment: it seems that if i remove the PDO commands, it works fine. idk whats the issue tho